# ASP .NET Core 3.1 and Storage Account connection

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-storage-account

I have inherited an ASP .NET Core 3.1 application deployed as an Azure API App. The application uses a storage account, but I'm having trouble figuring out how ASP.NET Core connects to the storage account.

I see that the application code obtains the storage connection string:

```js
string storageConnectionString = configuration["StorageConnectionString"] ? ?
  throw new ArgumentNullException($ "{nameof(OperationStorageManager)}.{nameof(storageConnectionString)}");

if (!CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageConnectionString, out _storageAccount)) throw new ArgumentException($ "{nameof(OperationStorageManager)}.{nameof(storageConnectionString)}");

_tableName = configuration["Storage:TableName"] ? ?
  throw new ArgumentNullException($ "{nameof(OperationStorageManager)}.TableName");
```

The application is currently running and successfully connecting to the Azure storage account.

However, I am having trouble locating the file or configuration setting where the connection string is saved. I have checked the Azure API App configuration settings but cannot find a "StorageConnectionString". Can someone please help me locate the file or configuration setting where the connection string is stored?

Comment: Are there any additional `IConfiguration` sources set up? Is the project using Key Vault? Also, I know it may sound silly, but I have to ask this: have you checked **all** `appsettings.json` files? There could be multiple, nested under the main one.

Comment: @Prolog Thank you, you point me on the right direction. it was on the Key Vault secrets values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Prolog` for the comments.

The connection string for the storage account can be stored in the `appsettings.json` file of the application code.

- You can find the file in the `root directory` of the application.
- The connection string is stored in the `StorageConnectionString` property.
- You can also check the Azure API App configuration settings to see if the connection string is stored there.
- The configurations set in the  `appsettings.json`  will be deployed to the  `App service`  -  `Configuration`  - `Application Settings`  section.

[image]

Taken reference from [MSDOC.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#configure-storage-to-run-locally)

**For local settings:**

- `local.settings.json`  is for working in the local environment.
- And if you deploy the application with that file, you will be seeing the  `local.settings.json`  file is not deployed to  `Azure`.

After deployment of `ASP.NET Core 3.1.`

[image]

[image]

[image]

After deployment the App settings won't be available in the configuration section of deployed App.

If you want to make the values to be available, then you need add the settings in the configuration section.

[image]